# Filtering one array on the basis of another array

Tags: r

I have two arrays 'check' and 'path' , I wish to select only those elements in check which are not present in path. I have done it in the following manner, is there a more efficient manner to do it?

```
check<-rbind(c(1,0),c(0,1),c(9,9))
path<-rbind(c(1,1),c(1,2),c(0,1),c(10,10))
new.check<-check[-(which(duplicated(rbind(path,check)))-nrow(path)),]
```

setdiff() did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not more efficient, but more correct:

```
new.check <- check[ setdiff(1:nrow(check),(which(duplicated(rbind(path,check)))-nrow(path))),]
```

Using `-` indexing will result in incorrect result if there are no duplicates - say `check <- rbind(c(1,0),c(9,9))`

*Edit:*

Or interchange `path` and `check` in `rbind()` and use `fromLast=TRUE`

```
new.check <- check[ setdiff(1:nrow(check),which(duplicated(rbind(check,path),fromLast=T))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using setdiff and %in%

```
# get the elements in check that are not present in path
elements <- setdiff(unique(as.vector(check)),unique(as.vector(path)))
# convert check to data frame to access columns by name
checkd <- data.frame(check)
# check if either column has the required elements - if yes, extract that row
checkd[checkd$X1 %in% elements | checkd$X2 %in% elements ,]
```